# How do I cycle through a set of images?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a banner that cycles through 3 images using JavaScript.
Each image should be displayed for 10 seconds before changing.

I wrote some code but it is not working. It stays stuck on the first image. The Image does not change as I want it to.

Can you see anything in the code and point out my mistakes?

Code as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeBanner(){
        var img = new array

        img[0] = document.images[0].src
        img[1] = document.images[1].src
        img[2] = document.images[2].src

        var currentimg = img[0]

        if(currentimg == img[0]) {
            currentimg = img[1]
        }

        if(currentimg == img[1]) {
            currentimg = img[2]
        }
    }
</script>
```

HTML as follows:

```
<body onload="var start=setInterval('changeBanner()', 10000;">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div>
            <img src="budda.JPG" width="900px" height="300px" />
        </div>
...
```

Comment: 'It doesn't work'...care to be more descriptive about that? *How* does it not work?

Comment: Double-check your syntax. You're at least missing a parenthesis in your call to `setInterval()`, and you would be better off writing `var img = [];` to create your array.

Comment: Apologies for not being more specific. It stays stuck on the first image. Images does not change as I want it to

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee as Frederic said, you have some syntax issue. Do you know how to debug JS code on your browser?

Comment: I strongly recommend using Chrome and looking in the debug console (just right-click anywhere in the document and select "inspect element"). From what I can see in that code you don't have 3 images referenced in your document for example, so there's gonna be errors related to that.

Comment: Or install firebug if u prefer firefox over chrome
As for the code : U will need to change the src attribute of the image as well :
      If (.....)
          ..
      document.getElementById('giveYourImgAnId').src = currentImage;

Comment: Chrome gives me the error "array is not defined" Im guessing it is a problem with the deceleration of my array...?

Comment: Try []  instead of new array and there is a closing bracket missing in setInterval.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var index = 0;

function changeBanner() {
    [].forEach.call(document.images, function(v, i) {
        document.images[i].hidden = i !== index
    });
    index = (index + 1) % document.images.length;
}
window.onload = function() {
    setInterval(changeBanner, 1000)
};
```

http://jsbin.com/emilef/2/edit

Answer (score 1):

```
function changeBanner(){
var img = new array

img[0] = document.images[0].src
img[1] = document.images[1].src
img[2] = document.images[2].src

var currentimg = img[0]
```

Now `currentimg` is `img[0]`

```
if(currentimg == img[0]) {
```

This will be true
        currentimg = img[1]
    }

Now `currentImg` has the value `img[1]`

```
if(currentimg == img[1]) {
```

This will be true as well

```
    currentimg = img[2]
}
```

`currentImg` has the value of `img[2]`

}

Now lets though away the value of `currentImg`

You need to 1) sort out the logic 2) set a certain DOM object to this new value.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has several functional issues:

- The code in the onload attribute of the body tag was not closed correctly
- The code inside changeBanner will always execute all if statements, never progressing with the image cycle

Regardless of the fixes you can make the code a little cleaner, remove in-line scripts form the body tag and fix the if statement issue by using an index to track the current image in the set.

Assuming you have HTML like yours, with 3 images all starting of `hidden`:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x150" width="300px" height="150px" hidden />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/200x250" width="300px" height="150px" hidden />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x350" width="300px" height="150px" hidden />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

You don't need to use the `onload` attribute of the `body`.

Using `window.onload` instead you can assign a function which will automatically be called after the `load` event, which is after the DOM is ready and all images are loaded.

Preferably you would have all your script code inside a separate `.js` file and only include the reference to it in your HTML. However, I did stay close to your current approach for simplicity.

Within that function you can set-up your variables and then start the interval, similar to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentImageIndex = -1,
        maxImageIndex = 0,
        images = [],
        changeInterval = 1500;

    // prepares relevant variables to cycle throguh images
    var setUp = function() {
        images = document.images;
        maxImageIndex = images.length;
        currentImageIndex = 0;
    };

    // changes the banner currently being displayed
    var changeBanner = function() {
        var i;

        // either re-set the index to 0 if the max length was reached or increase the index by 1
        currentImageIndex = (currentImageIndex >= maxImageIndex - 1) ? 0 : currentImageIndex += 1;

        for (i = 0; i < maxImageIndex; i += 1) {
            images[i].hidden = (i !== currentImageIndex);
        }
    };

    // a function which is triggered following the `load` event
    window.onload = function() {
        setUp();

        images[currentImageIndex].hidden = false; // show the first banner image;

        setInterval(changeBanner, changeInterval); // following a delay, keep changing the banner image by the specified interval
    };
</script>
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nqjy4/) - Fixing the logical issues and using `windows.onload()`

---

Answer (score 0):

Check this out in console ;)

```
var imgs=document.images;
function changeBanner(){
    var firstImgSrc = imgs[0].src + "";
    for(var i=0;i<imgs.length-1;i++){
        imgs[i].src=imgs[i+1].src+"";
    }
    imgs[imgs.length-1].src=firstImgSrc; //replace last image src with first one
}
var interval = setInterval(changeBanner, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `setInterval('changeBanner()', 10000;` in your code is not closed properly, it has missing ")" after 10000. It should be:

```
setInterval('changeBanner()', 10000);
```

Also, the setInterval function will only be called when the body is loaded. So just add the function in your JavaScript file instead and link it to the html. Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeBanner(){
    var img = new array

    img[0] = document.images[0].src
    img[1] = document.images[1].src
    img[2] = document.images[2].src

    var currentimg = img[0]

    if(currentimg == img[0]) {
        currentimg = img[1]
    }

    if(currentimg == img[1]) {
        currentimg = img[2]
    }
}

  setInterval('changeBanner()', 10000);
</script>
```